# Post Chat message using Graphapi via Powershell using Delegate Grant type

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

Post Chat message using Graphapi via Powershell using Delegate Grant type using password grant

#Group chat Message

```
$granttype = 'password'
$tenantID = '695bbc7172e0'
$scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
$clientSecret = (ConvertTo-SecureString "O4UN4ndB" -AsPlainText -Force )
$cred = Import-Clixml C:\temp\credentials.xml
$redirectUri = "https://testexchangeewsdelegate.com"
# Construct URI
$uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

# Construct Body

$body = @{
clientId = "0e003e593d"
scope         = $scope
grant_type    = $granttype
username      = $cred.UserName
password      = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().password
}

$TokenResponses = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody
$apiUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/19:987345050c22c8369df1a6@thread.v2'
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Tokenresponses.access_token)"} -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

$apiUrl1 = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats/19:987345050c22c8369df1a6@thread.v2/messages'

$params = @{ 
Body = @{ Content = "Hello World"} }

$bodyJSON = $params| ConvertTo-Json

Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Tokenresponses.access_token)"} -Uri $apiUrl1 -Method Post -Body $bodyJSON -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Help me to update group chat post using PowerShell via graph api

Comment: Help me to update group chat post using PowerShell via graphapi , able to retrieve group chat message but unable to post message chat either it says 400 bad request or 412 precondition failed

Comment: Can you share us the whole error message what you are seeing? Are you trying to update a message or post a new message?

Comment: Post message 
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
At C:\Users\temp\Untitled2.ps1:32 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($Tokenresponse

Comment: Can you share the document which you are using for the API call?

Comment: Have you tested in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge), the api calls that you are making?

Comment: no documentation available for sending chat in teams , Yes it is working using delegated permission